# Why can a non-capturing closure be used after transferring ownership?

Tags: rust, closures, borrow-checker, ownership

I'm trying to understand ownership in Rust and faced a misunderstanding related to transfer ownership. Consider the following code:

```
fn main() {
    let closure = || 32;
    foo(closure);
    foo(closure); //perfectly fine
}

fn foo<F>(f: F) -> u32
where
    F: Fn() -> u32,
{
    f()
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ef90a5c0dc707163674f743c4d8fcead)

I thought that the ownership should be transferred and the second call `foo(closure)` should not be allowed.

Why does it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your closure implements `Copy`, so when you use it a second time, a copy is automatically made. Your code works for the same reason this does:

```rust
fn main() {
    let v = 32;
    foo(v);
    foo(v);
}

fn foo(a: u32) -> u32 {
    a
}
```

See also:

- [Do all primitive types implement the Copy trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41413336/155423)
- [Why does "move" in Rust not actually move?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53465843/155423)
- [Can you clone a closure?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27883569/155423)
- [How do I clone a closure, so that their types are the same?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49470366/155423)

Comment: Thanks for the point. Indeed the behavior is well-specified in the [reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/closure.html#other-traits): _A closure is `Clone` or `Copy` if it does not capture any values by unique immutable or mutable reference, and if all values it captures by copy or move are `Clone` or `Copy`, respectively._

Comment: This is kind of offtopic for that specific question, but I'd like to clarify one point regarding captured closure. Assuming a closure captures some variable and take ownership of it with `move` specified before the argument list. If the reference to the variable is used in the closure's body will the lifetime of the captured variable be the same as the closure's one and the closure will be the `Fn`, not `FnOnce`?

Comment: @SomeName `move` and what traits are implemented are two separate concepts. See [When does a closure implement Fn, FnMut and FnOnce?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30177395/155423). For the lifetime question, see [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32300133/155423), specifically the paragraph starting with "A lifetime is a bit of metadata "